# Wireshark POST data

Tags: post, methods, wireshark

This is the captured data from wireshark

```
POST /r HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.4; GT-I9100 Build/IMM76L)(en-us)
Cache-Control: no-transform
Host: xx.xx.xx.xx
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 77

WLL202GUI#00000058$CuII4425339CnsI4425339CzsXT3BQnVOa1ZR0OL0+0hLWwgCksHiqQ0V5HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Server: piled
Keep-Alive: timeout=30, max=300
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 103

WLL202GUI#00000084$ChsN989338254856CcsD98Cvsb90ccdc057d52d0e53d906f963aabcfa7CqsI4425339CmsHPedr@mCgIC1
```

What I know is that this is the POST data:

```
WLL202GUI#00000058$CuII4425339CnsI4425339CzsXT3BQnVOa1ZR0OL0+0hLWwgCksHiqQ0V5
```

and this the response:

```
WLL202GUI#00000084$ChsN989338254856CcsD98Cvsb90ccdc057d52d0e53d906f963aabcfa7CqsI4425339CmsHPedr@mCgIC1
```

(correct me if i'm wrong)

what is the full URI path for this? is it :

```
http://xx.xx.xx.xx/r
```

followed by the above data?

i mean how can i send the same post data and recieve the same response? or change some of the data ?

this packets was sent by an app from an android OS (using BlueStacks to be exact)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The post data immediately follows the headers you pasted and should be visible in the tree.

It is not secured by SSL. If it were, you wouldn't be able to read the headers like you have.